# Python IndentationError in executing my code

Tags: python

I am just learning python. And I was trying to write a simple code like this.

```
def isPrime(n):
    a=0
    if n==1:
        print("1 is special")
    for x in range(1,n):
        if n%x==0:
        a=a+1   
    if a==2:
        print("{} is prime".format(n))
    else:
        print("{} is not prime".format(n))
for n in range(2,20):
    isPrime(n)
```

Then I get an error which states "IndentationError: expected an indented block" at line 7. What's the error actually? Can anyone help? Sorry if that was silly. I am completely new to python.

Comment: Any time you see a colon at the end of a line, the next line needs to be indented. The error is extremely accurate/informative

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies in the second if statement:

```
def isPrime(n):
    a=0
    if n==1:
        print("n is special")
    for x in range(1,n):
        if n%x==0:
            a=a+1                #this line should be indented as it currently is
            #can also be written as: a+=1
    if a==2:
        print("{} is prime".format(n))
    else:
        print("{} is not prime".format(n))

for n in range(2,20):
    isPrime(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if n%x==0:
a=a+1 <-- needs to be indented
```

The error is literal, when you see that, look at your loops, if statements, and functions to see if the lines proceeding it are indented.